# RequestBody always null while attaching file not string data

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I'm using Retrofit version 2.5 and i have seen all documentation and questions related to it, but i didn't find any solution yet. Here problem is, RequestBody for file always becomes null after attaching file. Here i have attached my code, please have a look at this-

```
          final RequestBody msgbody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), messege);
                final RequestBody idbody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), String.valueOf(id));
                //map.put("userId", idbody);
                //map.put("message", msgbody);
                RequestBody fbody = null;
                if (fileUri!=null) {
                    String path = FileUtils.getPath(getContext(),fileUri);
                    File file = new File(path);
                    fbody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(getContext().getContentResolver().getType(fileUri)), file);
                    //RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file);
                    //fbody = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), body);
                    Log.e("SUPPORT",path+" body:"+new Gson().toJson(fbody));
                    //map.put("file\"; filename=\""+file.getName()+"\"",body);
                }

                Call<SubmitTicket> call = mInterface.issueTicket(idbody,msgbody,fbody);
                Log.e("SUPPORT",new Gson().toJson(call));
                call.enqueue(new Callback<SubmitTicket>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<SubmitTicket> call, Response<SubmitTicket> response) {
                        loadingBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        submitBtn.setEnabled(true);
                   }
                   @Override
                   public void onFailure(Call<ResponseModel> call, Throwable t) {
                      t.printStackTrace();
                      Log.i("Error :",t.getCause()+"");
                      Log.i("Error :","T");
                      finish();
                   } //error even before compile**
            });
```

And here is interface code,

```
@Multipart
@POST("Support")
//Call<SubmitTicket> issueTicket(@PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> params);
Call<SubmitTicket> issueTicket(@Part("userId") RequestBody id, @Part("message") RequestBody messege, @Part("image\"; filename=\"myfile.jpg\" ") RequestBody file);
```

Thanks for all answers and comments.

Comment: Which part is null ?

Comment: look at code, variable fbody in if condition becomes null after attaching file.

Comment: Why this line is commented     `//fbody = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), body);` ?

Comment: did you debug and check if your `file` is null or not?

Comment: No, file is not null

Comment: fbody is commented because i have tried it also.

Comment: this is returning a wrong path: `FileUtils.getPath(getContext(),fileUri);` - basically you CANNOT get any real file path from the `Uri`

Comment: Yes, it gives real path of file. File Utils working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Use this, this helps you. You need to send file in Multipart form data.

Your Interface will look like this:

```
 @Multipart
 @POST("Support")
 Call<SubmitTicket> issueTicket(@Part("userId") RequestBody id, @Part("message") RequestBody messege, @Part MultipartBody.Part file);
```

And your request will be like this:

```
  RequestBody msgbody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "yourMessage");
        RequestBody idbody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "id");


        if (fileUri!=null) {
            String path = FileUtils.getPath(getContext(),fileUri);
            File file = new File(path);

            // create RequestBody instance from file
            RequestBody requestFile =
                    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);

            MultipartBody.Part body =
                    MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), requestFile);



        Call<SubmitTicket> call = mInterface.issueTicket(idbody,msgbody,body);
        Log.e("SUPPORT",new Gson().toJson(call));
        call.enqueue(new Callback<SubmitTicket>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<SubmitTicket> call, Response<SubmitTicket> response) {
                loadingBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                submitBtn.setEnabled(true);
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseModel> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
                Log.i("Error :",t.getCause()+"");
                Log.i("Error :","T");
                finish();
            } //error even before compile**
        });

        }
```

This is always helping me. Hope that these will also useful to you and others.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to change in your interface. Instead of using `@Part RequestBody file` use `@Part MultipartBody.Part file` as follows -

```
@Multipart
@POST("Support")
Call<SubmitTicket> issueTicket(@Part("userId") RequestBody id, @Part("message") RequestBody messege, @Part MultipartBody.Part  image);
```

then in your request part use `Mulitpart.Part` body instead of `RequestBody` as
follows -

```
MultipartBody.Part fbody = null;
                if (fileUri!=null) {
                    String path = FileUtils.getPath(getContext(),fileUri);
                    File file = new File(path);
                    //here **image** is your remote file param name
                    fbody = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.getName()+System.currentTimeMillis(), RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file));

                    Log.e("SUPPORT",path+" body:"+new Gson().toJson(fbody));
                    //map.put("file\"; filename=\""+file.getName()+"\"",body);
                }
```

Comment: @Krishna Vyas try this

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, so what I did was to change this 'fbody' part of the code and add a custom method to return the Multipart body:

```
      final RequestBody msgbody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), messege);
            final RequestBody idbody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), String.valueOf(id));
            //map.put("userId", idbody);
            //map.put("message", msgbody);
            MultipartBody.Part fbody = null;
            if (fileUri != null) {
                Log.e("SUPPORT",path+" body:"+new Gson().toJson(fbody));
                fbody = prepareFilePart("img", fileUri);
                //map.put("file\"; filename=\""+file.getName()+"\"",body);
            }

            Call<SubmitTicket> call = mInterface.issueTicket(idbody,msgbody,fbody);
            Log.e("SUPPORT",new Gson().toJson(call));
            call.enqueue(new Callback<SubmitTicket>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<SubmitTicket> call, Response<SubmitTicket> response) {
                    loadingBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    submitBtn.setEnabled(true);
               }
               @Override
               public void onFailure(Call<ResponseModel> call, Throwable t) {
                  t.printStackTrace();
                  Log.i("Error :",t.getCause()+"");
                  Log.i("Error :","T");
                  finish();
               } //error even before compile**
        });
```

I added one emthod for creating the formdata here:

```
@NonNull
private MultipartBody.Part prepareFilePart(String partName, Uri fileUri) {
    File file = FileUtils.getFile(this, fileUri);
    // create RequestBody instance from file
    RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(file, MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"));
    // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
    return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(partName, file.getName(), requestFile);
}
```